# firefox focus homepage

Tags: 12.04, firefox, focus

On firefox's latest version, using tabmixplus or otherwise, is it possible to give focus to the page when a new tab is opened (which is the homepage, in my case), rather than the address bar ?

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to [New Tab Homepage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/) add-on page. There is *Add to Firefox* button. **Right Click** on it and click *Save Link As*. Save the link in *xpi* format.
 2.Now extract the just downloaded *xpi* file into a folder(say *newtabhome*).
 3.Now open *newtabhome>chrome>content>tabhomepage.js* in your favorite editor. Comment out this piece of code(Lines 60-64):

```
if (gURLBar)
  setTimeout(function() { 
    // if page is about:blank select() works just like focus, two birds one stone
    gURLBar.select();
  }, 0);
```

4.Next type this command inside *newtabhome* directory:
`zip -r newtabhome.xpi *`
 5.Open the newly created *newtabhome.xpi* file with Firefox and install the hacked add-on.

**Shortcut(Might NOT work):**
Download [this add-on](http://www.mediafire.com/?v1113g9noytswdv). For installing, just open the file with firefox. [Source](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/791190)